# Exception: Autowired annotation requires at least one argument

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, amazon-web-services

I have this error. On localhost everything is ok. The error is on AWS. What could be the reason?

```
   HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Autowired annotation requires at least one argument: public com.bartek.controllers.AppController()

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Autowired annotation requires at least one argument: public com.bartek.controllers.AppController()

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Autowired annotation requires at least one argument: public com.bartek.controllers.AppController()
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Autowired annotation requires at least one argument: public com.bartek.controllers.AppController()
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:296)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod.createWithResolvedBean(HandlerMethod.java:255)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:323)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:61)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:351)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1131)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.39 logs.
```

.

```
@Controller
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    public AppController(){ 
    }

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionAnnotationFactory();

    @RequestMapping(path="/index", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path="/addproject/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addProject(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person, Project project, Model model){

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();   

        Person p = new Person();
        p.setName(person.getName());
        p.setSurname(person.getSurname());
        p.setIndex(person.getIndex());

        Project pr = new Project();
        pr.setContent(project.getContent());

        try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<Person> listPersons = new ArrayList<Person>();
        listPersons.add(p);

        pr.setPersons(listPersons);

        session.save(pr);       
        session.save(p);        
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            throw e;
        }
        return "redirect:/listprojects";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path="/addproject", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String start(){

        return "addproject";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path="/listprojects", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getListProjects(Model model){

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        try {
        session.beginTransaction();

        List<Project> listProjects = new ArrayList<Project>();
        listProjects = session.createCriteria(Project.class).list();

        model.addAttribute("lists", listProjects);
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            throw e;
        }
        return "listprojects";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path="/addperson", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addPersonSite(Model model){

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        try {
        session.beginTransaction();

        List<Project> titleProjects = new ArrayList<Project>();
        titleProjects = session.createCriteria(Project.class).list();

        model.addAttribute("titleList", titleProjects);
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            throw e;
        }
        return "addperson";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path="/addperson/add", method={RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
    public String addPersonForm(@RequestParam(value = "nameProject", required=false) String nameProject, @ModelAttribute("person") Person person, Project project, Model model){

        int idProject;
        List<Person> listPersons = new ArrayList<Person>();
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();   

        Person p = new Person();
        p.setName(person.getName());
        p.setSurname(person.getSurname());
        p.setIndex(person.getIndex());

        try {
        session.beginTransaction();

        List<Project> listProjects = new ArrayList<Project>();
        listProjects = session.createCriteria(Project.class).list();

        Project pr = new Project();

        for(Project pro : listProjects){
            if(pro.getContent().equals(nameProject)){
                idProject = (pro.getId() - 1);          
                pr = listProjects.get(idProject);       
                listPersons = listProjects.get(idProject).getPersons();
                listPersons.add(p);
                pr.setPersons(listPersons);
            }
        }

        session.saveOrUpdate(pr);       
        session.save(p);        
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            throw e;
        }

        return "redirect:/listprojects";
    }

}
```

.....................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 5):

You have set `@Autowired` on your default constructor, which makes no sense. There is nothing to autowire, hence the error message.

Comment: but, AWS requires a default constructor. What to do?

Comment: Delete the `@Autowired` annotation

Comment: That's a database connection error, so it looks like you are past the `@Autowired` issue.